# bash replace string with shorter string regular expression

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file where I have extracted strings to, from other files.
The problem is some of the extracted strings have extra data at the end of them that I need to delete, because of some off formatting.
Please how do I reduce this:

```
eqwerty&entryPoint=main&something=1238094007035&firstName=Isaac&protocol=http
```

to just this:

```
eqwerty
```

(The first string on the line before the "&"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run it through `sed` like so:

```
sed -e 's:&.*::' <yourlogfile>
```

add the `-i` flag if you want to modify the file in place

Comment: Thanks. I shamefacedly already found this. And I was coming back to repent of my RTFMedness.

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH string manipulations:

```
s='eqwerty&entryPoint=main&something=1238094007035&firstName=Isaac&protocol=http'

echo "${s%%&*}"
```

**Output:**

```
eqwerty
```

Comment: i would generally recommend avoiding doing this kind of string replacement in the shell as it will be pretty slow with long strings & large log files.  running it through sed (or any other such binary) will tend to be faster.  especially if the string is non-ASCII.

Comment: **it will be pretty slow with long strings** Please provide some links of the benchmark showing evidence of slowness.

Comment: it's fairly trivial to test this yourself.  i don't have the scripts off hand that i used to benchmark in the past when doing large shell script development.

Comment: ok then I suggest let's leave the speculations aside as OP never mentioned anything about having 10MB data in single line.

Comment: (1) i already said "generally" and not "always" (2) as a *general* recommendation, my suggestion still stands (3) it doesn't take MB of data before the bash inefficiency is overtaken by a pipe+fork, it's more like KB.  whether the OP (or anyone else stumbling over this comment) finds the recommendation useful is up to them.

Comment: [Here is a demo with with 75kb data](http://ideone.com/8Y5Mc2) that shows `sed` is slowest, `cut` is somewhat better but bash string truncation is fastest.

Answer (score 1):

`cut -f 1 -d '&' filename` will also work.

```
>>>echo 'eqwerty&entryPoint=main&something=1238094007035&firstName=Isaac&protocol=http' | cut -f 1 -d '&'
eqwerty
```

Answer (score 0):

If `awk` is used maybe these might help:

```
awk -F'&' '{print $1}' file
eqwerty
```

If `awk's` field separator is set to the character to remove, You can then get the parts you want as $1

```
awk '{sub(/&.*/,""); print}' file
eqwerty
```

Using `gsub()` to substitute it with an empty string

Comment: Thank you! Awk-fu is always appreciated. I am really struggling with it so I always bow down to those who know its tao.